# Intuition for $e$ and natural logs

Tags: exponentiation, eulers-number-e

I understand that $e$ is "the growth constant", and I understand that it was derived by:
$$
\lim_{ n \to \infty} (1 + 1/n)^n.
$$
But how does raising $e$ to $rt$ work, wouldn't it be like raising
$$
\lim_{ n \to \infty} (1 + 1/n)^{nrt}?
$$
Why does that work (if it works at all), and is there any intuition behind how. Also why is this useful? Thanks in advance!

Comment: $e^{rt}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\color{red}{n}rt}$

Comment: More relevant though is $e^{rt}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{rt}{n}\right)^{n}$.

Comment: $e$ was not "derived" from that limit. $e$ was derived from $\log e=1$, and $\log$ was derived from $\int_1^xt^{-1}\,dt=\log x$.

Comment: That's a matter of taste. I find limits of sequences much more fundamental than a definition via integrals.